# How to convert a for loop to a while loop?

Tags: python

```
def print_names(names):

    """Print the names in the list of names, one per line"""

    for name in names:

        print(name)

print_names(['John', 'Mary', 'Donald'])
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? This is fine.

Comment: Well, you could say `while names: print names.pop(0)` assuming that the list is throwaway but I'm curious why you'd want to do this. Iterating over a list is a natural place to use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most straightforward (there are shorter ways, but this seems most equivalent):

```
def print_names(names):
    i = 0
    while i < len(names):
        name = names[i]
        print(name)
        i += 1  # make sure to increment before any 'continue'
```

Comment: Might be nice to say `name = names[i]` at the top, so you don't need to refactor the rest of the loop body

Comment: Now consider that someone uses `continue` in the loop body. `i` won't be incremented. Since you now no longer use `i` after the first lineof the loop, you can move the increment to the  second line of the loop

Comment: @JohnLaRooy On the other hand, on all occasions that I can think of (for-loop with enumerate, forloop-counter in django templates, etc.) the loop variable is constant throughout the entire loop body, and for good reason, I believe.

Comment: The `for` loop you are refactoring doesn't have an explicit index. If it were an enumerate loop, you can work around this of course - making the code less and less elegant. But you can never rely on the last line of the loop being executed.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy Point taken, added a comment. Still, having the same index around for the whole body seems more intuitive to me. In the `for i in range(len(names))` variation, the increment is also the last thing happening in each iteration (where I do get that it happens for any `continue` statements as well)

Answer (score 1):

In general one may convert any `for` loop to an equivalent while loop like so:

```
for X in Y:
    S
```

becomes:

```
it = iter(Y)
try:
    while True:
        X = next(Y)
        S
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

So, your program becomes:

```
def print_names(names):
    """Print the names in the list of names, one per line"""
    it = iter(names)
    try:
        while True:
            name = next(it)
            print(name)
    except StopIteration:
        pass

print_names(['John', 'Mary', 'Donald'])
```

Answer (score -1):

You could simply put the for loop inside of a while loop.

```
def print_names(names):

    """Print the names in the list of names, one per line"""

    running = True:
    while running:

        for name in names:

            print(name)

print_names(['John', 'Mary', 'Donald'])
```

Comment: `print_names` is an infinite loop. It will never return.

Comment: infinite as pointed out, but even if you fix that you still have the for-loop, which is, me thinks, not in the sense of the OP.